# how could I generate xsd dynamically

Tags: java, dynamic, jaxb, xsd

I want to generate a xsd file dynamically, I don't want to use jaxb because it creates alot of files when I use schemagen and I want the schema in one file only.

any idea?

Comment: you want to generate XML or XSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a JAXB runtime to generate an XML schema it should produce one Result per namespace URI:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JAXB/GenerateSchema